# Visibility expression error in ssrs 2008 table column

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

[image]Dears,

I have a table that is grouped by Currency, and when i export to excel it splited into sheets based on Currency Grouping and each sheet has Currency Name.

[image]

i need to set Visibility Expression to last 2 columns to be hidden if the currency is USD.

ive tried

`=IIF(Fields!Currency1.Value="USD",True,False)`but all sheets are hidden

ive tried

`=IIF(Globals!PageName="USD",True,False)`it gave me error global variables can only be used in headers and footers.

also

=`IIF(First(ReportItems!Claim_Currency.Value)="USD",True,False)`also error.

can any one advise ,

Regards,

Comment: I can't see any reason why the first won't work (the other two are wide of the mark).  If your dataset includes a field called Currency1, and if you're setting the Hidden property of each column (make sure this is the case), can't see what could be wrong.  You can hide the columns in Excel, but not when viewed interactively, by testing if the RenderFormat global variable = "EXCEL".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dataset Field Values use Parameter values to show or hide.

For eg:

=IIF(INSTR(Join(Parameters!Currency.Value,","),"USD")=0,True,False)